# Servlet return null stream for Captcha

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, captcha

i have a servlet that generates captcha on my jsp page  but many time i got null from this servlet and getting invalid captcha error,i tried a lot but  still don't know why i get this here is my captcha servlet

```
public class CaptchaServlet extends HttpServlet {


  protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request,
                                HttpServletResponse response)
                 throws ServletException, IOException {

    int width = 200;
    int height = 42;

    char data[] = RandomStringUtils.randomNumeric(4).toLowerCase().toCharArray();


    BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(width, height,
                  BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

    Graphics2D g2d = bufferedImage.createGraphics();

    Font font = new Font("Georgia", Font.BOLD, 18);
    g2d.setFont(font);

    RenderingHints rh = new RenderingHints(
           RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
           RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

    rh.put(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING,
           RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);

    g2d.setRenderingHints(rh);

    GradientPaint gp = new GradientPaint(0, 0,new Color(144, 46, 54), 0, height/2, new Color(144, 46, 54), true);

    g2d.setPaint(gp);
    g2d.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);

    g2d.setColor(Color.white);

    Random r = new Random();

    String captcha = String.copyValueOf(data);
    System.out.println("In captcha Servlet :-  "+captcha);
    request.getSession().setAttribute("captcha", captcha );

    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;

    for (int i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
        x += 35 + (Math.abs(r.nextInt()) % 5);
        y = 20 + Math.abs(r.nextInt()) % 5;
        g2d.drawChars(data, i, 1, x, y);
    }

    g2d.dispose();

    response.setContentType("image/png");
    ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "png", os);
    byte[] bytes = os.toByteArray();
    ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
    out.write(bytes);
    os.close();
  }


  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                       HttpServletResponse response)
                           throws ServletException, IOException {
      processRequest(request, response);
  }


  protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
                        HttpServletResponse response)
                            throws ServletException, IOException {
      processRequest(request, response);
  }
}
```

below is my jsp code

```
<div id="captcha_div">
<img id="captcha_img" src="<%=appContext%>/CaptchaServlet"
style="float: left; width: 70%; margin-top: 2%;">
<div style="padding-top: 5%; margin-left: 73%">
<button class="refresh" onclick="javascript:regenImage();"type="button">  
</button></div></div>
```

i check captcha code and user entered code in another servlet like

```
            String code = request.getParameter("code");
            String captcha = (String) session.getAttribute("captcha");
            if (captcha != null && code != null) {
                if (captcha.equals(code)) {
                    isValid = true;
                }
            }
```

i rarely get null ,One situation i reproduce is like when the login page is keep ideal for 10,20 minutes i get value of captcha is null and because of this i got invalid capcha error can you please tell me why i get null or what i did wrong in my code Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

Can you please place your processRequest code inside try catch and also check what is printing in logs for below code while making a request.

```
String captcha = String.copyValueOf(data);
System.out.println("In captcha Servlet :-  "+captcha);
request.getSession().setAttribute("captcha", captcha );
```